# Collect the identifier of a Button in a row of a CollectionView in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, command

I am developing an application in xamarin forms and I have problems accessing the event of a button that I have in a CollectionView. For each button that is selected, depending on the row it is in, it will do a different thing with the id.

My xaml code with the CollectionView is as follows:

```
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="{Binding id_cliente}"
                           TextColor="black"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    
                    <Label 
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Text="{Binding categoria}"
                        FontAttributes="Italic"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           TextColor="black"/>

                    <Label Grid.Column="3"
                        Text="{Binding descripcion}"
                           TextColor="black"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    
                    
                    <Label 
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Text="{Binding estado}"
                           TextColor="Yellow"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        FontAttributes="Bold" />


                        <Button Grid.Column="5" Text="Confirmar" BorderColor="#2b3c3c" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#4ba862" TextColor="White"  HeightRequest="60" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="btnconfirmar" Clicked="ButtonConfirmacion_Clicked" Command="{Binding id_trabajo}"/>
                        
                        <Button Grid.Column="6" Text="Asignar" BorderColor="#2b3c3c" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#4ba862" TextColor="White"  HeightRequest="60" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="btnasignar" Clicked="ButtonListaTrabajos_Clicked"/>

                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

And in the cs code of that page I have:

```
private void ButtonConfirmacion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Trabajo selectedItem1 = e.CurrentSelection[0] as Trabajo;

    }
```

This code, when that row is selected, with an OnSelectionChanged (sender, e) method if it picks up the item which has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code below to get the `x:Name` of button in a row.

```
private void ButtonConfirmacion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        var button = sender as Button;
        var elemets = (button.Parent as Grid).Children;

        foreach (var item in elemets)
        {
            if (item.GetType().Name == "Button")
            {                   
                var btn_name = item.StyleId;     
                
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That works partially, indicating if the row is a label or a button, but really knowing in which row (id) said button has actually been pressed within a ContentView is what I don't get

Comment: Adding a var job = item.BindingContext; is partially achieved, but I cannot access its items from the Work object

Comment: I am not sure what you really want. Could you provide more details? What does this `access its items from the Work object ` mean?

Comment: If you want to get which button pressed, you could use the code `var button = sender as Button; var s = button.StyleId;` in button click event directly.